# How can post-shaving pimples be prevented?

Tags: shave-shaving, shaving-cream

It is common to get scattered pimples after shaving one's face with a razor.

How can it be prevented?

There are after-shaves - some with alcohol, others without - as well as lotions and gels.  Do these work?

Comment: Welcome!  On HealthSE, we can't answer individual advice questions, and your question was likely to be closed.  I edited to remove the indivdual information, as well as to correct your usage of acne (there is a difference between acne and post-shaving pimples or razor bumps), and now the question is more answerable.  If you disagree please revert it and edit it as you see fit.  :)

Comment: See Meta for why we can't answer medical advice

Comment: "Post-shaving pimples" are also called razor bumps, ingrown hair or pseudofolliculitis barbae. There are a lot of articles available, like this: https://www.dermnetnz.org/topics/folliculitis-barbae/ .